# Remove tag in header: alternate

Tags: hooks, meta-tags, 10

is it possible to delete a tag from our **head** tag (see it below)

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="da" href="http://mysite.local/page1" />
```

I looked in interface (MetaTag and also on page) and have not found anything about 'alternate'.
I found a few articles saying I have to do it using hooks but I want to ensure that is the only way.

p.s. we are on Drupal 10.

Thanks.